# Soma de uma coluna não está dando o valor esperado

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho uma tabela fictícia com duas colunas e alguns dados nela, conforme a imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu executo a minha instrução SQL a seguir, o resultado da consulta é 22. O resultado não deveria ser apenas 12? Eu não consegui entender o porquê.

Alguém poderia me explicar?

SQL:

```
SELECT sum(a.coluna1)
  FROM dados AS A 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TRUE 
                 FROM dados AS B
                 WHERE (a.coluna1/b.coluna2) >= 1);
```

Comment: Resolveu sua questão ?

Comment: **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português (SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Answer (score 1):

Esse seu SQL não faz muito sentido, acredito que o que você quis fazer foi o seguinte:

```
 SELECT sum(coluna1)
 FROM dados 
 WHERE ((coluna1/coluna2) >= 1)
```

Vê se dessa forma funciona.

O que esse SQL que eu te mandei faz, é somar os valores quando a coluna1 / coluna2 for maior ou igual a 1.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que na `subquery` você diz que a linha atual da **tabela A** quando dividida por **qualquer** linha da **tabela B**, o resultado for `maior/igual` a 1, você irá somar o valor da coluna 1.

Usando a sua mesma sintaxe, para resolver esse problema, basta especificar que no `subselect` a linha de onde se pega a **coluna B** deve ser a mesma linha da **coluna A**, Veja o exemplo:

```
SELECT sum(a.coluna1)
  FROM dados AS A 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TRUE 
                 FROM dados AS B
                 WHERE a.coluna1 = b.coluna1 and (a.coluna1/b.coluna2) >= 1);
```

**Porém, Este código não faz muito sentido...**

Como o colega Isaias demonstrou, não faz muito sentido dar um `subselect` com `Exists` para fazer esse calculo, basta fazer como ele fez.

Answer (score 0):

Analisando seu SQL:

```
SELECT sum(a.coluna1)
  FROM dados AS A 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TRUE 
                 FROM dados AS B
                 WHERE (a.coluna1/b.coluna2) >= 1);
```

Ele retorna 22 porque você diz para ele somar a coluna `a.coluna1` quando a condição passada na cláusula `WHERE` entre `"()"` existir, ela retornou `TRUE`, portanto ele somou, caso retorna-se `FALSE` ele não somaria nada.

---

Acredito que seria isso que você queria:

```
SELECT SUM(a.coluna1)
  FROM dados AS a
 WHERE id IN (SELECT id
                FROM dados AS b
               WHERE (a.coluna1 / b.coluna2) >= 1);
```

Assim, sua consulta irá somar os dados da coluna `a.coluna1` onde o `id` existir dentro da condição passada na clausula `WHERE` entre `"()"`.